# ERROR UserGroupInformation: PriviledgedActionException as:user1 (auth:SIMPLE)

Tags: apache-spark

When I am trying to run a program in a remote spark machine I am getting this below exception:

```
15/01/16 11:14:39 ERROR UserGroupInformation: PriviledgedActionException as:user1 (auth:SIMPLE) cause:java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Futures timed out after [30 seconds]
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException: Unknown exception in doAs
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1421)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkHadoopUtil.runAsSparkUser(SparkHadoopUtil.scala:59)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend$.run(CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend.scala:115)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend$.main(CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend.scala:163)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend.main(CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend.scala)
Caused by: java.security.PrivilegedActionException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Futures timed out after [30 seconds]
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1408)
        ... 4 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Futures timed out after [30 seconds]
        at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.ready(Promise.scala:219)
        at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.result(Promise.scala:223)
        at scala.concurrent.Await$$anonfun$result$1.apply(package.scala:107)
        at scala.concurrent.BlockContext$DefaultBlockContext$.blockOn(BlockContext.scala:53)
        at scala.concurrent.Await$.result(package.scala:107)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend.scala:127)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkHadoopUtil$$anon$1.run(SparkHadoopUtil.scala:60)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkHadoopUtil$$anon$1.run(SparkHadoopUtil.scala:59)
```

I am executing this driver class in one machine say(abc) but the spark is installed on another machine (xyz:7077).
When I execute the same driver class pointing to "local" it works fine.

```
public class TestSpark implements Serializable{


        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
                TestSpark test = new TestSpark();
                test.testReduce();
        }

        public void testReduce() throws IOException {

                SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("spark://xyz:7077").setAppName("Sample App");
                String[] pathToJar = {"/home/user1/Desktop/Jars/TestSpark.jar"};

                //SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("spark://abc:7077").setAppName("Sample App").setJars(pathToJar);
                //SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local").setAppName("Sample App");

                JavaSparkContext jsc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);

                List<Integer> data = new ArrayList<Integer>();

                for(int i=1;i<500;i++){
                        data.add(i);
                }

                System.out.println("Size : "+data.size());

                JavaRDD<Integer> distData = jsc.parallelize(data);

                Integer total = distData.reduce(new Function2<Integer, Integer, Integer>() {
                        @Override
                        public Integer call(Integer v1, Integer v2) throws Exception {

                                return v1 + v2;
                        }
                });
                System.out.println("-->"+total );
        }
}
```

I have also tried setting spark.driver.host :: xyz & spark.driver.port :: 7077 while creating the spark context, but it did not help.

Please advice

Comment: Have have the same issue. Is related to setJars?